# Should you include uncited papers in your CV?

Tags: publications, citations, cv

Is it convenient to include in your CV papers that have not been cited at all along several years?

Comment: Please flesh out your question.  What do you mean by "convenient"?  Why do you care about whether it's convenient?  The purpose of a CV is not your convenience.  I can't understand what you are asking.  Take a look at http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, then think about how to edit your question to provide more details, context, your thoughts, etc.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Convenient? No.  Appropriate?  Yes.

Unless you are at a point in your career where you can release an impressive "selected publications" CV, your CV is expected to contain everything that you have ever published.  That includes publications that nobody has cited and even ones that you are embarrassed by in retrospect.  I've certainly got some of those in my CV (we were all grad students once), and I simply trust that they will be drowned out by all of the good work that has been done since.

Comment: Somebody once said that, unlike real doctors, scientists are forgiven their worst work and judged on the basis of their best.

Comment: By publication you mean just journal papers? Apart from many conference abstracts, I also do not include a paper my supervisor published in a predatory journal with me as a coauthor, I really don't wait when they will be drowned out, I am embarrassed about it now and I think it can even endanger me now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. Your cv is about you, not about the people who cite you. It will give the reader an opportunity to see how you write, how you think. And what you have done over the years.